# numpy not-equally distant range of numbers

Tags: python, numpy

Using np.linspace(0,3,100) would give a range of numbers that are equally distant between 0 and 3. what's the best way to get a range of numbers between 0 and 3 but more densely close to 3 and less dense in the beginning, perhaps in a logarithmic way.

----------edit

(np.log10(1), np.log10(4), 100)-1 gives more dense samples close to 0 than 3.

In addition is there also a more mathematically explicit way?

------edit:

This is the best I myself could come up with:
s = -1*(3*10**(-np.linspace(0,4,25))-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight improvement over `np.logspace` is [`np.geomspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.geomspace.html), which is more convenient since endpoints can be specified directly. rpoleski's answer then becomes

```
4 - np.geomspace(1, 4, 25)[::-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [`np.logspace()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logspace.html). You will need to use `np.log10()` for arguments.

Comment: I tried this: np.logspace(np.log10(1), np.log10(4), 25)-1, but it seems more dense close to 0 than 3. Do you know how I can make it the other way arround?

Comment: `4-np.logspace(np.log10(1), np.log10(4), 25)[::-1]`